# Caro-Kann continuation for Black in this position

Tags: caro-kann

I would like to ask your help regarding this position. I played as Black in this game in a tournament and it has ended in a draw by repetition.

Now I fear that I may encounter this position again, so I would like to ask help about what are the plans for Black in this position and what should I do if White decides to put his Queen to h3?

```
[Title "Caro-Kann continuation and plans for Black"]
[StartPly "36"]
[SetUp "1"]
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]

1. e4 c6
2. d4 d5
3. Nc3 dxe4
4. Nxe4 Bf5
5. Ng3 Bg6
6. h4 h6
7. Nh3 Nf6
8. Nf4 Bh7
9. Bc4 e6
10. O-O Be7
11. c3 O-O
12. Re1 Nd5
13. Qh5 Qd6
14. Qg4 Nf6
15. Qf3 Nd5
16. Qg4 Nf6
17. Qd1 Nd5
18. Qg4 Nf6
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Regarding the issue with move 13, I actually couldn't remember if it was a blunder or just a move order issue. But my point is after move 18, what plans should be followed by Black in order to play actively?

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering about the purpose of 13... Qd6. Seems a waste of time to me. What's wrong with grabbing the pawn? White's 13. Qh5 is a simple mistake.

And about the point that "draw with Black is as good as a win" - it is *not*. You should aim for a win with both sides and also ignore rating gaps. I've given up the habit of looking at my opponent's rating before the game. Just play.

Comment: Hi, maybe it's a blunder, but what I actually want to discuss is how Black should continue this game after move 18 and what his plans are.

Answer (score -1):

draw because you are black and a draw as black is equal to a win. Depends on your rating. If by a hundred and less no problem. But more than that you have to play for that win by playing Nd7, not Nd5